# Processing: Ellipse is not growing with 0.5 but with any value above 1?

Tags: processing

EDIT: i got it. it has to be float instead of int.

I'm an absolut beginner at programming in processing.

For some reason I can add any value above 1.0 and the code is working. But if I'm using e.g. 0.5 it's not working and I absolutely have no clue why.
It's about an ellipse that should grow every draw-function.

```
//variables
int size = 10;
float growth= 0.5;

void setup() {
size(500, 500);
background(0,255,0);

}

void draw() {
fill(200);
ellipse(pmouseX,pmouseY,size,size);
size += growth;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data type of size is `int`. If you add 0.5 to an integral data type, then the value of the variable want change. 
Note, `(int)0.5` is equal to 0 - Try `print( (int)0.5 );`

Change the data type of `size` from `int` to `float`, to solve your issue:

```
float size   = 10.0;
float growth = 0.5;

void setup() {
    size(500, 500);
    background(0,255,0);
}

void draw() {
    fill(200);
    ellipse(pmouseX,pmouseY,size,size);
    size += growth;
}
```